# ASP.NET VB.NET how do i modify HTML at runtime

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

Can anyone tell me how to modify HTML at runtime please?

A user has pasted a table from Word into a text editor control (FCKEditor)

The editor control automatically converts to HTML however I want to change the HTML before saving to database.

So, I want to make this

```
<table width="600" height=100>
```

into this

```
<table>
```

before saving string to the database.

Have tried using XmlDocument but LoadXml method doesn't like

```
&nbsp;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I'm going to get bashed by the agility pack people here, but if you've got a known pattern that you're looking to target its okay to use RegEx.

```
'Source Text
Dim text = "<table width=""600"" " & vbNewLine & "height=100>" & vbNewLine & "<td>hello</td>" & vbNewLine & "</table>"
'Replace all table tags just empty table tags
text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, "<table.*?>", "<table>", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

Comment: I agree - regular expressions are the way to go here. Loading up a DOM in memory just to do a search and replace seems like overkill to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (free / open source) to load the HTML into a DOM. Then you can manipulate it there.